# Get value from type point in php

Tags: php, sql, point

I have a field in the database of type POINT (phpMyAdmin). I use this column to save gps coordinates. 
Now I want to extract the value of latitude and longitude from database. 
Can I do that without having to add other fields?

```
$query="SELECT * FROM risk_disposal WHERE id=$id";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{echo "$row2['gps']";}
```

[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJojZ.png)

Comment: using a select statement you can retrieve just the two values you are looking for.

Comment: the select statement retrieves me this "H�2�s�D@�8�ߡ�3@"

Comment: can you post the exact query such as 'SELECT lat, long FROM table WHERE'

Comment: Show your sql and values you see in ssms for more assistance. You may try to cast it to a varchar in your select `CAST(yourField as varchar(256))`

Comment: Did you tried with `ST_AsText(columnName)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
SELECT ST_X(point), ST_Y(point) FROM ...
```